# Optional or Repeated Items in Prolog DCG

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg, ebnf

So I'm writing a simple parser for Pascal in SWI-Prolog using Definite Clause Grammars.

I don't understand how to implement repeating (2 or more) or optionally repeating (1 or more) predicates.

For example, in EBNF, for Pascal's "program" is:

```
"PROGRAM" identifier "(" identifierlist ")" ";" block "."
```

Where "identifierlist" is:

```
identifier { "," identifier }
```

and "identifier" is:

```
letter { letter | digit }
```

I know in prolog's DCG form program is:

```
program --> ["PROGRAM"], identifier, ["("], identifierlist, [")"], [";"], block, ["."].
```

How do I implement "identifierlist" or even "identifier", which contains an optionally repeating number of "identifier" or "letter" or "digit" predicates?

Comment: When you say "optionally repeating" do you mean it could be empty? Your definition of `identifierlist` doesn't seem to indicate so.

Comment: If it could be empty "identifierlist --> []." should do the trick. So, I don't believe I'm referring to an empty case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Prolog, you can just about write it exactly as the EBNF as long as the EBNF is really what you intend.

```
identifierlist = identifier { "," identifier }
```

You could also write this as:

```
identifierlist = identifier
identifierlist = identifier , identifierlist
```

In Prolog, you would write this as:

```
identifier_list --> identifier.
identifier_list --> identifier, ",", identifier_list.
```

If you want to include an empty identifier list, then it's a little more elaborate:

```
identifier_list --> [].
identifier_list --> nonempty_identifier_list.

nonempty_identifier_list--> identifier.
nonempty_identifier_list--> identifier, ",", nonempty_identifier_list.
```

Your original EBNF does not include an empty identifer list. If it did, the above code might look a lot like the EBNF.

---

As @false points out in the comments, another rendering of `nonempty_identifier_list` is:

```
nonempty_identifier_list --> identifier, ( [] | ",", nonempty_identifier_list ).
```

Comment: That's along the lines of what I thought would be the case would be; however, my experience is so limited with Prolog that I did not know for certain.

Comment: @MisterCrazy8 you get used to it. :) Having multiple clauses for a predicate gives you that "OR" effect.

Comment: @MisterCrazy8 if you find my answer acceptable, perhaps you could mark it accepted, or let me know if there's anything else I can clarify.

Comment: And, `nonempty_identifier_list --> identifier, ( [] | ",", nonempty_identifier_list ).` might be preferabe

Comment: @false, thanks, I wasn't sure about it. I considered the other syntax and went with the "explicit" view, but yes, I could do it that way.